# Count (unique) views Spring boot REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring boot application with RESTful services, JWT based authentication and react as front end.

I want to build in a counter that monitors the unique user requests (e.g. per day) to certain REST endpoints in my RestController and stores the current value to a column in the database.

Specifically I'd like to know how many users clicked on a certain article (`api/articles/{id}`) per day and bind that value to the entity.

Entity:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "Article")
public class Article{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "message_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "visits")
    private Long visitCounter;

    ...
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/articles")
public class ArticleController {

    private AppUserService userService;
    private ArticleService articleService ;

    @Autowired
    public ArticleController (AppUserService userService, ArticleService articleService ) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.articleService = articleService;
    }


    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Article> getArticleById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long  articleId) {
        Article article = articleService .getArticleById(articleId);
        if(article == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
         articleService.countVisit(); //???
         return ResponseEntity.ok().body(article);
    }
}

...
```

Any ideas how something like that could be accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have application scoped bean *ArticleCountService*. The service should have a `Map<String, Set<String>>` for counters.

The key is article path (or id or something to identify your article). The value is set of users (e.g. IP addresses to identify unique users you can get from *HttpServletRequest*). At 23:59:999 you get the map data and create a new empty map.
That's the simplest solution but it could have memory impact.

The mode convenient way is to store something in DB. E.g.
ARTICLE_ID, USER_ID (IP), VISIT_DATE

And once a day aggregate the data (obsolete rows from yesterday could be removed after the calculating.)